# NodeJS: Adding new child nodes to JSON Object

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, swagger-node-express

lets say there is `customer` object, i need to add new element `address` to this json object `customer`. how can I achieve this?

Both of these are not altering the `customer` JSON object

```
customer['address'] = addressObj 

customer.address = addressObj
```

and I can not use `push()` as this is not adding a new item in list of objects.

Thanks,
Naren

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your addressObj is not properly formed.

This works for me:

```
var customer = {"name": "Naren"};
customer.address1 = "stackoverflow";
customer.address2 = {"fulladdress":"stackoverflow"};
JSON.stringify(customer)
```

Output:

```
"{"name":"Naren","address1":"stackoverflow","address2":{"fulladdress":"stackoverflow"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not clear on what exactly you want to do but it sounds to me as if you want have a JSON and want to merge it with another JSON, creating just a JSON file.

```
 let Json1 = {'Superman': 'Favorite' };
 let Json2 = {'Supergirl': 'Greatest'};
 let Json3 = {'IronFist': 'Top 10' };
```

You now want to add Supergirl (the new element) to Superman (the old element) I assume. Take a look here @ [merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-json) a simple package which does its job well. You would code as follows:

```
use strict;
var mergeJSON = require("merge-json");
let Json1 = {'Superman': 'Favorite' };
let Json2 = {'Supergirl': 'Greatest'};
let Json3 = {'IronFist': 'Top 10' };
let Json6 = mergeJSON(Json1,Json2);
Json6=mergeJSON(Json6,Json3);
```

You would end up with as follows:

`Json6 = {'Superman': 'Favorite', 'Supergirl': 'Greatest', 'IronFist': 'Top 10'}`

This is how I make use of combining JSON information or text information into a JSON file. You can get much more sophisticated with the module mentioned above. (Just do not confuse [merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-json) with json-merge and other modules.)

If this is not what you are looking for my apologies, then I did not understand the question correctly.